# Подставить ruby переменную в bash

Tags: bash, ruby

В `ruby` скрипте необходимо выполнить `bash` код с подстановкой рубишной переменной. Как это можно сделать?
Сейчас мучаю конструкции вида:

`test = "string"
system 'echo $("#{test}")'`

Желательно не выносить bash в отдельный скрипт с передачей ему переменных, а выполнить через system.

Answer (score 2):

Так ведь аргумент для `system` завёрнут в одинарные кавычки. Интерполяция не будет работать. Нужно обернуть в двойные. Кавычки внутри либо экранировать, либо заменить на одинарные:

```
test = "here"
system "echo \\'#{test}\\'" #=> 'here'
system "echo \\\"#{test}\\\"" #=> "here"
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться обычной интерполяцией `#{}`, только следует помнить, что она работает либо в двойных кавычках,

```
test = "string"
system "echo '#{test}'"
```

либо в обратных (в этом случае можно обойтись вообще без метода `system()`)

```
test = 'ls -la'
puts `#{test}`
```